# Spell checker software

Tags: asp.net, spell-checking, google-api

I have been assigned a task to find a decent spell checker (UK English) preferably the free one for a project that we are doing.

I have looked at Google AJAX API for this. The project contains some young person's (kids less than 18 years old) data which shouldn't allow exposing or storing outside the application boundaries. Google logs the data for research purpose that means Google owns the data whatever we send over the wire through Google API. Is this right? I fired an email to Google regarding the privacy of data and storage but they haven't come back. If you have some knowledge regarding this please share with me.

At this point our servers might not have access to external entities that means we might not be able to use Web API for this over the wire. But it may change in the future. That means I have to find out some spell checker alternatives that can sit in our environment and do the job or an external APIs.

Would you mind share your findings and knowledge in this regard. I would prefer free services but never know if you have some cracking spell checker for a few quid’s then I don't mind recommending to the project board.

Technology using ASP.NET 3.5/4.0, MVC, jQuery, SQL Sever 2008 etc

Cheers,
Naren

Answer (score 1):

[GNU aspell](http://aspell.net/) might be suitable for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

[Yandex](http://api.yandex.ru/speller/doc/dg/tasks/how-to-spellcheck-web.xml) provides one. It is mainly targeted to Russian-speaking auditory, but it contains a dictionary for the English as well.